# Can't properly install Meteor 0.6.1

Tags: javascript, meteor

I recently wanted to update to Meteor 0.6.1 from 0.5.4 and just did a `meteor update` in terminal. Immediately got an error in my terminal that gets thrown basically when I try anything.

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/martijn/.meteor/meteor: line 35: cd: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/martijn/tools/meteor.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I removed all of Meteor for a complete reinstall:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/meteor
rm -rf /usr/local/meteor

curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

Same error when I try to create a Meteor project in my Sites directory. Can't figure out whats causing this, it used to work great in my Sites directory. The only way to avoid this error is to paste all the docs, examples, packages, scripts and tools folders into my `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/martijn/` directory along with my projects which is very messy.

Was thinking that it might have to do something with that I'm running two harddrives in my Macbook, an SSD for the OS and HDD for my documents. `/usr/local/bin` where meteor gets installed is on my SSD. This seems to me like something is off with the paths of the installation, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Great. I would have accepted your answer if it was one by the way. Thanks, Meteor has been an absolute joy to use so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a bug in how we escape directory names. You hit this because your home directory has a space in it ("Macintosh HD"). I believe I fixed this just now, and the fix should be released in 0.6.2: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/c059c384fdf9e7169f25cc36d86fbc0ed0a9da83

Comment: I tried the changes in that commit you posted, and it seems to throw another error for me:

`/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/martijn/Sites/.meteor/tools/10262b5aa8/tools/meteor.js:1038
}).run();`

Either way, I'll accept your answer because you're aware of it and I'll gladly try again on 0.6.2.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for this information. When 0.6.2 is released (real soon), you'll have to do a complete re-install: Delete `/usr/local/bin/meteor` and `~/.meteor` and run the initial install script: `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Luckily I had another computer with Meteor where the upgrade worked.  So here is what I did:

I noticed that usr/local/bin had very different files in the working and not working computer.  So I just copied all the files from the working computer into the non-working one.  Now meteor works on both.  Not sure it's the best approach, but solved my issue.  Meteor commands work once more.

Hope this helps,

Paul

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I don't have another installation somewhere but I'm sure this will get fixed.